# Join obj or JSON object in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have java script object. when I write it on console by console.log(myobj) output is -

`[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`

Means five items

And after convert into JSON by JSON.stringify(myobj) output is -

```
"[{"x":"Account - AE1009"},{"i0":"13110.00"},{"i01":"2110.00"},{"i012":"0"},{"i0123":"1600.00"}]"
```

But I want join all items of array or JSON into one . Expected result given below. Input can be "myobj" or converted JSON give above.

```
[{"x":"Account - AE1009","i0":"13110.00","i01":"2110.00","i012":"0","i0123":"1600.00"}]
```

In nutshell i want join all items into one item.

Comment: `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]` is what you want.

Comment: "I want output like this in jquery" : quite unclear. Please try to explain better, using punctuation and sentences...

Comment: Its java script object and when we use console.log(myobj) output is - [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good thing to do, but you can acheive the desired result like this http://jsfiddle.net/zL5x6xxm/

```
var obj=[{"x":"Account - AE1009"},{"i0":"13110.00"},{"i01":"2110.00"},{"i012":"0"},{"i0123":"1600.00"}]

String.prototype.splice = function( idx, rem, s ) {
    return (this.slice(0,idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};
var newObj=JSON.stringify(obj)
newObj=newObj.replace(/{/g, '').replace(/}/g, '');
newObj=newObj.splice( newObj.length-1, 0, "}" );
newObj=newObj.splice( 1, 0, "{" );
console.log(newObj);
```

**Note:** The reason why i say it is bad, is because you will not be able to convert it back to object again